# How to sort a list based on the number within each LI.span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort the list of LI's based on the number that's in the span within each LI. I've looked at plugins that can do this but that's not what I want.

Can someone show me how you would sort a simple list how I stated above? I really don't have any idea where to even start, I don't know if it's complex or simple.

Here is my code:

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #252525;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  background-color: #353535;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

li span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li> Cups
    <span>12</span>
  </li>

  <li> Plates
    <span>18</span>
  </li>

  <li> Forks
    <span>03</span>
  </li>

  <li> Knives
    <span>06</span>
  </li>

  <li> Bowls
    <span>08</span>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you should use:

```js
function sortEm(a, b) {
  return parseInt($('span', a).text()) < parseInt($('span', b).text()) ? 1 : -1;
}

$('li').sort(sortEm).prependTo($('ul#test'));
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #252525;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  background-color: #353535;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

li span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test">

  <li> Cups
    <span>12</span>
  </li>

  <li> Plates
    <span>18</span>
  </li>

  <li> Forks
    <span>03</span>
  </li>

  <li> Knives
    <span>06</span>
  </li>

  <li> Bowls
    <span>08</span>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Nice one. That seems to work. I'm still mucking around trying to get $.map() to play nice.

Comment: in your example, the very last list item isn't in the right place, do you know why this is? I couldn't figure it out. it's the '08'

Answer (score 3):

You should fill an array with all the `<li>` elements, sort this array using `sort()`, then `empty()` the list add `append()` the sorted elements.

Something like this :

```js
$("#doSort").click(function() {
  // store the li items
  var items = $('ul li').get();

  items.sort(function(a, b) {
    var valueA = $(a).find("span").text();
    var valueB = $(b).find("span").text();

    if (valueA < valueB) return -1;
    if (valueA > valueB) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
  // clear the list and re-add sorted items on button click 
  $("ul").empty().append(items);
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #252525;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  background-color: #353535;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}

li span {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li> Cups
    <span>12</span>
  </li>

  <li> Plates
    <span>18</span>
  </li>

  <li> Forks
    <span>03</span>
  </li>

  <li> Knives
    <span>06</span>
  </li>

  <li> Bowls
    <span>08</span>
  </li>

</ul>

<button id="doSort">Sort this list!</button>
```

Comment: Use Number(valueA) an Number(valueB) during comparison

Comment: I would wrap your `valueA` and `valueB` variables in `parseInt()` to stop un-natural sorting behaviour. This will work in this case, however if someone gets the sorting values from a string attribute, it wont sort correctly.